# WPF: How to display item selection list to the top in combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working to make combobox to make it display item list to the top of combobox button, but after so much solution, it's still not working. How i can make it ? I need some help

[image]

After so many method, still not working, sorry cause im just new in WPF.

Comment: See the template in the following link. Make the popup placement top rather than bottom. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Give your new template a key in resources somewhere and apply as the template of your combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derived the combobox and use the CustomPopupPlacementCallback to place your popup:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    class MyComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var popup = (Popup)Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this);
            popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
            popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = placePopup;
        }

        private CustomPopupPlacement[] placePopup(Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset)
        {
            var placements = new[] { new CustomPopupPlacement() };
           // adapt the value of point to place..
            placements[0].Point = new Point(0, -100);
            return placements;
        }
```

and use it inside xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyComboBox x:Name="cb" Width="100" Height="100" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Alice"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Bob"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Charlie"/>
        </local:MyComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

result:

[image]